# Partial derivatives for $f(x) = e^y(x \sin(x) - y \cos(x)) $

Tags: partial-derivative

i have to find the partial derivatives for x and y for this function: 
$f(x) = e^y(x \sin(x) - y \cos(x)) $

I am used to find partial derivatives for functions that follows this pattern:

$x^4+y^4-(x-y)^2$ (just an examples) ,but the first function is new to me and I don't know how should I tackle it. Any tips would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do the first one?

Comment: What in particular is different about the first function from the ones that you know how to differentiate? Informally, you take a partial derivative with respect to $x$ by differentiating with respect to $x$, treating $y$ as a constant.